# How to Clear Recent Projects List in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

Is there any way to clear Recent Projects in Android Studio 0.1.1 ?

Comment: ok.. anyway i found a shortcut...

goto below folder ;

\android-studio\config\options

[where \android-studio Folder has the studio.exe]

and open other.xml in Notepad and look for the tags like..

    <component name="RecentProjectsManager">       and  open file options.xml and look for <property name="file.chooser.recent.files" value=""> tag..

Comment: You should add this as an answer, not comment, if it already solved your issue.

Comment: Why doesn't Google just add a red [ X ] button in the top left of the "Recent Projects" list to clear the list ? Additionally right-clicking an item in the box exposes an option to "Remove from List" ... ideas like this are not rocket science

Answer (score 92):

All at once? No, but you can hover your mouse over the project name e hit `Delete` on your keyboard.

**UPDATE**

I don't know if it existed or was added in the lastests version, but open any project and go to `File >  Reopen` and select `Clear List`. Click OK on the confirmation dialog and next time you open AS the Recent Projects list should be blank.

Comment: On mac "fn" + Backspace/Delete

Comment: On the Mac with Android Studio 1.1.0, it's [ File ] -> [ Open Recent] -> [ Clear List ]

Answer (score 37):

Focus on the list > <kbd>Ctrl+A</kbd> > <kbd>Del</kbd> > <kbd>OK</kbd>.

Comment: for me, this is the best answer. You can remove individual records this way, which I was needed

Answer (score 22):

In new Android Studio  2018
 this feature is made even better
      **File -> Open recent**
and at the de-e-ep bottom of the showed up  projects  list, please  activate:     **->Manage projects**

Now you are able to delete any of them on your choice by clicking on crosses of the items.

Answer (score 14):

On Mac OS X :

1. On "Welcome to Android Studio" Screen
2. On the Right Side List "Recent Projects" just hover over the Project you want to clear (do not click)
3. Now press <kbd>Delete</kbd>, thats it!

Find Source [here](http://code2care.org/2015/delete-android-studio-projects/)

Answer (score 7):

Note, this solution is for a newer version of Android Studio than the poster requested. I'm adding this solution, since this is the first link that comes up on Google.

I'm running Android Studio 1.5 on Windows 7, and none of the above solutions worked. The only way I was able to remove projects from the recent list was by modifying the recentProjects.xml file. I found it at `C:\Users\{user name}\.AndroidStudio1.5\config\options\recentProjects.xml`

I just deleted all the option tags of the projects I didn't want. The structure looks like:

```
<application>
  <component name="RecentProjectsManager">
    <option name="recentPaths">
      <list>
        <option value="XXX>
```

Answer (score 4):

On **Windows**:

Android Studio 2.3.3

**File -> Close Project** close all the project which is opened now. By close project you will directed to **Welcome to Android Studio** page with list of projects in the recent list.

Just mouse over the project you want to delete and click the close button to remove the project from recent list.[image]

Answer (score 1):

Go to file in Android Studio, hover mouse on "Open Recent" and go to the end of list. At the end, click "Manage Project. A list of projects will be displayed. Select desired project by pressing Control and select the desired projects to be deleted. After selection right click on selected projects and click " Remove Selected from Welcome Screen".

Selection can be done by pressing shift and selecting project on top of the list and clicking at the end of list and remove as stated above.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way, at least with 2.0 and further versions: select the first item and afterwards select the last one on the list, so all of them will slightly change colour, and then right-click mouse and select delete all from the menu.

Answer (score 0):

step :1
File -> Close project ->

the left side we have all recent projects 
Step:2
select single or Multiple projects ->Remove the selection from the welcome screen