# How to remove ALL recent projects from Android Studio welcome screen in 2022 on Mac?

Tags: android-studio

On welcome screen of Android Studio (Bumblebee or more recent) on a Mac,

You can remove projects from the recent projects list one-by-one like this:

[image]

But, how do you remove ALL projects from the list of recent projects at the same time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Duplicate of:* [How to Clear Recent Projects List in Android Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17208322/how-to-clear-recent-projects-list-in-android-studio)

*But unfortunately the accepted answer is not up to date. Actually [this is the best answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21034362/7834341).*

Focus on the list > `Ctrl+A` > `Del` > `OK`.